# Determine axis of rotation from 4x4 transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

Background: Using a 3D scanner, I scanned an object that rotates around an axis in space from two rotations. I used iterative closest point to determine the 4x4 transformation matrix mapping one scan to the other. I aim to determine the line (defined by a vector and a point) around which the object is rotating.

I converted the transformation matrix to the axis/angle representation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation), and the axis seems to be in the correct direction, the angle of rotation is consistent with the amount the object was physically rotated, but I don't know how to determine a point along the axis of rotation.

I was hoping the 'translation' portion of the 4x4 transformation matrix was a point on the axis of rotation, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a 4x4 homogeneous transformation matrix, the point is either located in the last column or the bottom row, depending on conventions.  Note that the element at 4,4 is typically 1 and is ignored in this application.

Comment: I am using a 4x4 homogeneous transformation matrix I believe, and the convention in my case is the last column, but it's quite far off from where I know the rotation axis to be. I'm assuming (1,4), (2,4), and (3,4) correspond to X, Y, Z respectively of the point.

Comment: Yes, that is normally the case.  It is a point on the axis of rotation, but may not necessarily be close to where you would expect.   It could conceivably be any point on the line that correlates with the axis of rotation.